# Spark UDF using Annotations

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

trying to understand how to register udf using annotations(@udf) in spark but not getting any outcome but it works if I use spark.udf.register

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
def to_date_format_udf(d_str):
  l = [char for char in d_str]
  return "".join(l[0:2]) + "/" +  "".join(l[2:4]) + "  " +"".join(l[4:6]) + ":" + " 
   ".join(l[6:])
spark.udf.register("to_date_format_udf", to_date_format_udf, StringType())
str="02190925"
print(to_date_format_udf(str))
```

with this code I am getting the expected outcome:

```
2/19  09:25
```

but when I try to follow databricks documentation on @udf

I get the following outcome:

```
Column<b'to_date_format_udf(02190925)'>
```

Here is the modifications on databricks documentation:

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def to_date_format_udf(d_str):
 l = [char for char in d_str]
 return "".join(l[0:2]) + "/" +  "".join(l[2:4]) + "  " +"".join(l[4:6]) + ":" + "".join(l[6:])

print(to_date_format_udf("02190925"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the result is the expected output since the input is applied directly on the function `UDF` is not invoked at all and invocation is treated as a normal python call.

However the annotation [`@udf`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f570d01c0d009bb035d3c89d77661a5432f982cb/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L5414) also generally known as [`decorators`](https://pythonguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/decorator.html), modifies the behavior of the `to_date_format_udf` causing it to return an expression which will be evaluated by Spark when an action is taken.

Invoking `spark.sql('select to_date_format_udf("02190925")').show()` would yield the same result in both cases.